# Custom fit function involving multiple outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

```
class CustomModel(keras.Model):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="loss")
    self.mae_metric = keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError(name="mae")
    self.loss_functions=None

def compile(self, *args, loss=None, **kwargs):
    self.loss_functions = loss  # Store the provided loss functions
    super().compile(*args, **kwargs)

def train_step(self, data):
    x, y = data

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # Forward pass
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)  

        # Compute losses for each output

        loss2 = keras.losses.kullback_leibler_divergence(y_pred[2], y_pred[0])
        loss3 = keras.losses.kullback_leibler_divergence(y_pred[2], y_pred[1])

        # Aggregate total loss
        total_loss =loss2+loss3

    # Compute gradients
    trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
    gradients = tape.gradient([loss2,loss3], trainable_vars)

    # Update weights
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

    # Update metrics
    self.loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
    self.mae_metric.update_state(y[0], y_pred[0])  # Update metrics for output1
    return {"loss": self.loss_tracker.result(), "mae": self.mae_metric.result()}

@property
def metrics(self):
    return [self.loss_tracker, self.mae_metric]
```

> model

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(32,))
output1 = keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(10)(inputs)
output2 = keras.layers.Dense(1)(hidden1)
hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(10)(inputs)
output3 = keras.layers.Dense(1)(hidden2)

model = CustomModel(inputs, [output1,output2, output3])
```

> Compile the model with individual losses for each output which need to be overidden in train_step ideally

```
model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss=["mse","kullback_leibler_divergence",None])
x = np.random.random((1000, 32))
y = np.random.random((1000, 1))
model.fit(x,y)
```

I have three questions:

I don't want any loss to be applied to output3. Does passing None in the compile function will make that happen?

output1's loss in compile is passed as mse,but since I have used a different loss function  in the train_step will it be overidden?

How does tape.gradient([loss2,loss3], trainable_vars) this work? does it mean that loss1 will be applied only to output1 and loss2 only to output2?

I tried to do tape.gradient([loss2,loss3,None], trainable_vars) to meet my requirements but that doesn't work

Comment: What language is this written in? Python? Also, note that questions on Stack Overflow need to focus on one question. Please pick one of your question and focus on it instead, or your question is likely to be closed due to needing focus.

Comment: Yes in python , using tensorflow. All my questions are connected though, so all of them can be answered together?

Comment: Unfortunately no; someone could answer one of them and ignore the others, and technically that would be a valid answer. If several people did this for each question, how could you pick which one is the 'correct' one?